# How to right unit test code with mockery for Model class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I want to write test case using phpunit for following model function. I'm beginner to unit testing , Kindly please advice me.

```
public function checkUserEmailExist($email)
{

    $query = \registry::getDBHandler()->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :EMAIL");
    $query->bindValue(":EMAIL", $email);

    try{
        $query->execute();
        $result = ($query->fetchColumn());
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        \debug::error('MySQL errno ' . $e->getCode() . ': "' . $e->getMessage() . '" when executing: ' . $query->queryString);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: what does fetchColumn return? object or array ?

Comment: @user3360140 : object. it returns an email address

Comment: so if you do like echo $result->email you should get the email address? right?

Comment: Please check my answer. Why do you want to use mockery for this case?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to prepare your test bench for database testing with some test data. You can do so by following this tutorial:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html

Then you can write your test. Lets say your `checkUserEmailExist` method is in a class called `Authentication`. Then your test will look like the below:

```
<?php
class authenticationTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function testCheckUserEmailExist ()
    {
        $actual = 'dummyemail@testdatabase.com';
        $auth = new Authentication();
        $expected= $auth->checkUserEmailExist($actual);
        $this->assertEquals($expected->email, $actual);
    }
}
```

You need to make sure the `dummyemail@testdatabase.com` email exists in your `users` table of your test database.